# How is the usage of DBT better than using stored procedure method?

Tags: dbt

I have been using `stored procedure` method for a long time now.

As a part of sales report generation, I create `stored procedures` to `join/union all` mulitple tables in database  and call it using `python` whenever i need it.

Now `DBT` is a hot topic these days.

Whats the advantage of moving to `DBT` from `stored procedures` ?
Is there any point in migrating my entire `stored procedure` stack from stored proc to `DBT`?

Comment: Stored Procedures might give you an immediate solution, but they are difficult to track, maintain and test. It also makes your system virtually impossible to move to a different platform. While your Stored Procedure might do the transformation just fine, DBT goes further by understanding references between tables ('models'), applying tests, enabling a Dev/Test environment and integrating with Source Control. DBT allows you to apply good programming practices to data transformations. If you're a one-person team, you might not need it. But I wouldn't want to maintain your code.

Comment: Stored procs or functions can be source controlled pretty easily. There are some really good test frameworks as well like https://pgtap.org/ for PostgreSQL. dbt does have useful data tests built-in, but they mainly compensate for most DW's lack of constraints like uniqueness or FKs. Custom tests are easy to write in dbt though, and it comes back to the principal that the only SQL you write in dbt is `select` statements. All the table munging boilerplate is generated for you.

Comment: John is right, more people can collaborate using dbt vs those who can write effective sprocs. The upside of sprocs is they can be precompiled and use caches query plans. It's also a double-edged sword: "parameter sniffing" https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/ - It depends on what functionality you are using. Unioning a bunch of tables is a fairly trivial example - in fact it is a common example dbt use to illustrate the power of jinja macros to generate SQL for you e.g. https://docs.getdbt.com/blog/sql-union-all

Comment: Here is a [section](https://docs.getdbt.com/blog/migrating-from-stored-procs#step-3-execute) from an article from DBT that includes an example how DBT can be simpler than stored procedure.

Answer (score 4):

Some of the major benefits of dbt are:

1. Integration with version control (like git)
2. Support for multiple environments (dev and prod)
3. Dependency management and dag construction
4. Easily rebuild only a subset of your models with simple selection syntax
5. Automated testing
6. Jinja templating
7. Re-usable, complex logic like incremental materializations and snapshots
8. An auto-generated documentation website

More info in their [docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/introduction#what-makes-dbt-so-powerful) and marketing materials on their website, getdbt.com

Comment: SQL can be used with version control, especially if you use SQL migration tools like liquibase or flyway. That also lends itself to deployment across multiple environments. Jinja templating can be approximated with procedural extensions as in T-SQL, PL/SQL, PL/pgSQL. Other points are great. The biggest benefit you've missed is that dbt will generate and run SQL `create`, `update`, `merge` statements as well as do schema migration with `alter` for you. That's a lot of boilerplate you'd be doing in stored procs otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

As you've identified, dbt is functionally similar to a stored procedure, with some extras.

In order to have the functionality offered by dbt, source control etc. dbt exists outside of the database. While you might gain the features of dbt, you will also lose the functionality of a stored procedure, e.g., the ability to use temp tables, variables, or create parameterized queries.

You will also be constrained by dbt's use of Views to execute and manage queries. This limits you to language features your DB permits in Views and you wont have as many options to improve query performance than you would if you use a procedure.

Keep in mind that *some* of the functionality in dbt is available many major DBs:

- Dependency management - most DBs have system tables that can tell you how a Database object references another Database object. These can be queried in a way that shows dependencies forward and back.
- Templated SQL - Dynamic sql.
- Reusable logic - Functions and views.
- Tests - This can be achieved with stored procedures. A very good example of this is the [tSQLt](https://tsqlt.org/) framework for sql server. Tests in dbt are queries run by dbt.

Comment: This has a lot of good info in it, I have to disagree on a couple of points though. dbt does not constrain you to using CTEs, but it does use them behind the scenes. Whether CTEs are optimal can depend on whether the query engine can optimise them away or not; it's also pretty easy to write poorly performing stored procs. DBs don't do dependency management between user tables the way dbt can do it and order all the loads correctly in dependency order for you. DBs can only show you dependencies for views or for foreign keys.

Comment: Fair enough. Modified CTE comment. RE dependency management, the DB knows that Stored Proc X depends on Tables A, B, C, because the body of the proc refers to them, similar to dbt's `ref()`. DBs will do this for Procs, Views, and some other objects. It is also possible to use this information to construct a DAG for orchestration.

Comment: Ah yes I see you point regarding stored procs having their references contained within. As an aside, that info is harder to extract for lineage purposes unless you parse/tokenize the query. dbt has that info easily accessible in the object model.

Comment: Not quite. Most DB providers do track lineage. For example in Oracle there is the `all_tab_cols` system table, and others. Likewise, for example, in SQL Server there is `sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities` and others. These can be queried recursively to look forward or back along the lineage graph. Some DB providers will also do this to column level, which is even more useful. This is native DB functionality and doesn't require end-user parsing of the underlying query.

Comment: good to know, I wasn’t aware of those system tables. You would still have to do those recursive queries and if you wanted to visualize it then create your own. dbt has a web service you can run out of the box or use dbt Cloud to get access to. I notice that Databricks also has this functionality, the lineage is logged and there’s also a visualization of the DAG.

Comment: Would it suffice to say that DBT has kind of standardized some of these things that are done differently in different database? i.e. testing, lineage inspection.