# Running dbt vs scheduled queries on bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dbt

I am trying to see if there are any benefits to running dbt on bigquery as oppose to scheduled queries. Hence, what are the benefits?

Comment: In scheduled queries, it's harder to maintain a complex pipeline. Also, dbt can parallelise the jobs, however on BQ, it's just a single flow.
DBT depends on your codebase, so it helps to version the changes, so you can see all the history of your codes. 
DBT allows you to write SQL tests, to avoid any potential problems.
However, on the other side, either you have to pay for DBT cloud, or you have to setup a server for DBT to run the pipeline.
DBT also has a learning curve, since it's not 100% SQL, but it has DBT specific features / syntax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is the usage of DBT better than using stored procedure method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72550991/how-is-the-usage-of-dbt-better-than-using-stored-procedure-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If DBT runs a simple query, there is no real advantages. But in that case, I won't use Schedule queries, but Cloud Workflows, or Cloud Scheduler that invoque a BigQuery API call (jobs API, with a query job).

However, if you build a complex query, DBT can help you to create and maintain it, even to create temporary working table to get the final table.

But at the end of the day, DBT is simply a SQL query generator and you can schedule the output with the service that you prefer.